# python keeps saying that 'imput is undefined. how do I fix this?

Tags: python-3.x

Please help me with this. I'd really appreciate it. I have tried alot of things but nothing is working, Please suggest any ideas you have.

This is what it keeps saying:
     name = imput('hello')
NameError: name 'imput' is not defined

Comment: Check your spelling of input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled `input` as `imput`. `imput()` is not a function that python recognizes - thus, it assumes it's the name of some variable, searches for wherever that variable was declared, and finds nothing. So it says "this is undefined" and raises an error.

Answer (score 1):

`imput` isn't a built-in function. Perhaps you're looking for [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input).